# 2006 Mazda Tribute 6 cyl. P1450 P0442

Tags: mazda, tribute

I have been indicating a number of CEL codes, among them 0442, 0452 and 1450.  I've replaced the gas cap (twice), charcoal filter, fuel tank pressure sensor, canister purge valve and all the vacuum hoses.  I am still reading the 0442 and 1450.  Does anyone have a clue where to go from here?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!